# Perform segue not working inside api call

Tags: ios, swift, segue, modalviewcontroller

I have login page that use API call for checking credentials at the end i present main page as modal with performSegue like this :

```
@IBAction func loginPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    ApiHelper.userService { (service) -> Void in
        let query = GTLUserController.queryForLoginUser(email,password)
        service.executeQuery(query) { (ticket: GTLServiceTicket!, object: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if(error != nil){
                return
            }

            //Code...
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("mainSegue", sender: self)
        }
    }
}
```

The segue work fine when i launch the app for the first time, but when i terminate the app (using swipe) and login again the segue is not working i see the main page for 1s then it back to login.

N.B : the segue work fine when i use it outside the API call

Thank's in advance

Answer (score 0):

Never update the UI on a background thread, instead perform the segue on the main thread like so

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
  self.performSegueWithIdentifier("mainSegue", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: I already tried this, but it's not working. my segue only don't work when i kill the app and i relaunch it. in the first time it's working perfect without main thread